# Exposing Docker container port in Kubernetes config

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a Flask python API to Kubernetes (EKS). I've got the Dockerfile setup, but with some weird things going on.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8
 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 
EXPOSE 43594

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

I build the image running `docker build -t store-api .`.

When I try running the container and hitting an endpoint, I get `socker hung up`. However, if I run the image doing

```sh
docker run -d -p 43594:43594 store-api
```

I can successfully hit the endpoint with a response.

**My hunch is the port mapping.**

Now having said all that, running the image in a Kubernetes pod, I cannot get anything back from the endpoint and get `socket hung up`.

My question is, how do I explicitly add port mapping to my Kubernetes deployment/service?

Part of the `Deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: store-api
          name: store-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 43594
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
              name: store-api-claim0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

`Service.yaml`:

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 43594
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 43594
  selector:
    app: store-api
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

If I port forward using `kubectl port-forward deployment/store-api 43594:43594` and post the request to `localhost:43594/` it works fine.

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to in the Kubernetes case?  Is the Pod actually starting up (does `kubectl logs` show the Flask application's output)?  Is the Service correctly binding to the Pod (what does `kubectl describe service ...` show for `Endpoints:`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the response. Yep, the pod boots up as usual and the logs show that it's listening on the port I've assigned it. Describing the service, I get a `LoadBalancer ingress` URL but for Endpoints I have `<none>`.

Comment: If I port forward using `kubectl port-forward deployment/store-api 43594:43594` and post the request to `localhost:43594/` it works fine.

Comment: socket hung up is a nodejs error! kuber ingress controller and the other kuber components are written in go, your code is python! how come ?!

Comment: If the service description says `Endpoints: <none>` then the Service's `selector:` doesn't match the Deployment's `template: { metadata: { labels: } }`.  Double-check that.

Comment: You were bang on the money @DavidMaze. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

**Problem**

Output for `kubectl describe service <name_of_the_service>` command contains `Endpoints: <none>`

**Some theory**

From Kubernetes Glossary:

[Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-service)

> An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a
> network service. The set of Pods targeted by a Service is
> (usually) determined by a selector. If more Pods are added or removed,
> the set of Pods matching the selector will change. The Service makes
> sure that network traffic can be directed to the current set of Pods
> for the workload.

[Endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-endpoints)

> Endpoints track the IP addresses of Pods with matching selectors.

[Selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-selector):

Allows users to filter a list of resources based on labels. Selectors are applied when querying lists of resources to filter them by labels.

**Solution**

Labels in `spec.template.metadata.labels` of the Deployment should be the same as in `spec.selector` from the Service.

Additional information related to such issue can be found at [Kubernetes site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints):

> If the ENDPOINTS column is <none>, you should check that the
> spec.selector field of your Service actually selects for
> metadata.labels values on your Pods.